# Iterate through a formgroup containing formarrays

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I am creating a dynamic model-driven form with the following structure :

```
export class AppComponent {

  data = {
    companies: [
      {
        company: "example comany",
        projects: [
          {
            projectName: "example project",
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      companies: this.fb.array([])
    })

    this.setCompanies();
  }

  setCompanies() {
    let control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.companies;
    this.data.companies.forEach(x => {
      control.push(this.fb.group({ 
        company: x.company, 
        projects: this.setProjects(x) }))
    })
  }

  setProjects(x) {
    let arr = new FormArray([])
    x.projects.forEach(y => {
      arr.push(this.fb.group({ 
        projectName: y.projectName 
      }))
    })
    return arr;
  }
}
```

Below is the model structure, in the Observable of which I am receiving the data from the back-end:

```
export class Companies{
company : String;
companyRegNo : String;
projects : Project[];
}
export class Project{
projectName : String;
projectRegNo : String;
}
```

I have some json data in my 'myForm' `FormGroup` variable, with information containing company and projectName. I need to make some updations in this json, yet have the original `myForm` json data available with me.

Hence, I am creating another `FormGroup` variable `myForm2` and assigning `myForm` value to it :

```
myForm2: FormGroup;
this.myForm2 = this.myForm;
```

Now, I want the `company` value to be replaced with `companyRegNo` value and `projectName` value to be replaced with `projectRegNo` value keeping the keys `company` and `projectName` remain as it is, in myForm2.

I already have 2 methods, `getProjectRegNoFromProjectName()` and `getCompanyRegNoFromCompanyName()` available with me, which return the `projectRegNo` and `companyRegNo` on passing the `projectName` and `company` respectively. I need to call both these methods while iterating on myForm2.
How can I now iterate the `myForm2` data itself so that I may update the assigned attributes and `FormArray` values as aforementioned?

Comment: Sorry what exactly are you trying to do here again?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using patchValue?
Something like :

```
(<any>Object).values(formGroup.controls).forEach(control => {
      control.patchValue(value);
//Patch Your value here}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to this simple example of mine on nested form array.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-form-array-example?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Feel free to ask if any doubt.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your reference but I cannot find the answer to my question in your code.